# wecam H.264 http streaming Live

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I need solution for webcam live broadcasting. where broadcaster from his browser using a flash client and at the same time viewer's to use flash on computers and html http streaming on iso and handheld .

what I have figured out as of now is to use flash client for webcam broadcasting on flash player 11 for broadcasting the live video on FMS in H.264 encoding.  But what I am confused is  that will the FMS provide live stream for http to show on iso with ajax and on other hand flash viewer screen using rtmp, automatically or am I on the wrong track of understanding this.

What will be the best method to use flash client as broadcaster client for http streaming with ajax/html5 viewer client on ios devices, rtmp with flash viewer client on devices and pcs which support flash all though FMS.

Thanks.